# Совмещение библиотек в коде

Tags: html, css

коллеги!

А можно в одном коде писать несколько библиотек?! Например JS и JQuery  или в HTML вместе с разметкой добавлять Bootstrap...

И если можно, то как это влияет на рендеринг в браузерах..

Благодарен!

Comment: а кто может запретить ? вы на gsap посмотрите - 6 -30 src - если не webpach такая порнуха будет в html

Comment: На рендеринг не повлияет. Сейчас часто и так всё в одном бандле. Только во время разработки файлы лучше отдельные делать и потом вместе склеивать, потому что у них разные технологии/подсветки/подсказки/проверки/компиляции/транспиляции.